# Synchronization of map object

Tags: java, multithreading, dictionary, synchronization

I have a Map object which corresponds to a key value pair stored in a File.

```
private static Map myMap;
```

There is a manager class for this Map object which has a method getMap() which returns the object to the caller.

```
public static Map getMap()
```

It also has a synchronized method saveMap() which save the content back to the File

```
public static synchronized void saveMap(Map map)
```

The problem is that, there are threads which gets the Map object but don't want to save, i.e., they don't call the saveMap().

Suppose **thread1** gets the map object and makes a modification to it, i.e., add a key value pair to the map. **key1=value1** and once the task is completed, removes this key-value pair from the map. In between there is another thread **thread2** which adds another key-value pair to the map **key2=value2** and saves it before **thread1** actually remove **key1** from the map. This causes both key1=value1 and key2=value2 to be saved to the file.Which is not what I want.

How can i overcome this situation? I was thinking of modifying the getMap() method with something like

```
public Map getMap(boolean readonly) {
       if (readonly)
            return myMap.clone();
       return myMap;
}
```

Will this solve my problem?

Note: I don't want to use mutex and lock the Map object since I have long running processes which will block other threads.

Comment: If it isn't what you want, why are you allowing it to happen? Maybe you should be supplying *copies* of the map to the threads whose mods you don't want to save.

Comment: @EJP Isn't that what his proposed code suggests?

Comment: Whatever you're doing, if you have multiple threads making modifications to the map, your code is not thread-safe and, sooner or later, the map will be in an inconsistent state. You shouldn't expose the map at all. Encapsulate it in your class, and synchronize **every** access to the map.

Comment: ^+1^ Seems like the way to go.

Comment: Thnks every one. But I have long running processes which actually uses the map for only reading.

Comment: @Sonic it is a little known fact that only reading from a map from one thread, while another thread is writing to it, without both threads being properly synchronized, can cause your program to hang! This is  due to how the HashMap is implemented.

Comment: @RobinGreen : is the case same if the key and value of the map is immutable?

Comment: @sonic Probably. It is safest to assume that you always need to take explicit steps to be thread-safe. The Java memory model is very confusing and you don't know what the current or future implementation of third-party or Java platform classes will do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do one of two things.

The first one, which is the one I recommend, is DO NOT PASS OUT COPIES OF THE MAP.  There is no way to ensure values won't get lost/overwritten from interleaved gets/saved, aside from the multithreaded issues from not using a synchronized object.

In your manager class, removed getMap() and saveMap(), and replace them with getValue() and setValue().  I would make those methods synchronized, or replace the Map with a [ConcurrentMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentMap.html).  That way you don't have people holding on to instances of the whole map.

The second option would be to replace the Map with a [Hashtable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html). which is synchronized and thread-safe, but slower.  That would get rid of some, but not all, of your problems.  You still have loose references to the map running around your code.

Comment: Thanks . I will go for the option 1. Cheers :)

Comment: If you want a synchronized map, don't use the old, obsolete Hashtable. Use `Collections.synchronizedMap(anyMap)`.

Comment: @dj_segfault : If am using synchronized for each method, isn't there a chance of deadlock? Is it better to you some class level lock object? My methods are not static.